# How to extract numerical value from a substring in Julia

Tags: julia

I have substring that ends with numerical value.How can I extract this numerical value and assign it to a variable ?,a sub string for example:

```
"Size is x"
```

While x can actually be any number.

Since I find the resources for this language are somewhat limited compared to better known languages I had a hard time reaching for an answer

Answer (score 2):

once you've extracted the string, you can use [`parse`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/numbers/#Base.parse-Tuple%7BType,Any,Any%7D):

```
s="Size is 90"
number_as_string=split(s," ")[end]
number=parse(Int, number_as_string)
```